# xdmp:document-filter extracting embedded excel worksheets

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using `xdmp:document-filter` to extract text from binary documents. This works great, but I have an issue where in a say PPTX, if someone embeds an excel chart which is backed by excel sheet, PPTX embeds the excel spreadsheet as well. Now the `xdmp:document-filter` does extract the data from the embedded document. Is there a way for me to not extract the embedded documents ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you identify the embedded documents in the output XML?  If so, could you use XQuery to remove the embeded documents?